# Writing unit test with mocks

Tags: go, mocking

I wrote a REST api in it. Now I want to do its unit testing it by isolating different components.

The project structure looks like below and there are two major packages

```
├── main.go
├── routes
│   ├── routes.go
│   └── routes_test.go
├── db
│   └── db.go
```

**main.go**: Main entry point for the project

**routes/routes.go**: HTTP route handler package

**db/db.go**: database handler package

Now when I am testing the http routing I only want to test if the requests are routed to proper handler functions are then they respond accordingly. In real application the handler function would actually insert/update the database but I don't want to do that while testing. So if I can mock a database object and make my handler functions connect/read/write against that, but I am not sure how to do that.

When it comes to testing the database handler package `db.go`, I think i can't mock that and I have to either set up a test db against which I should make queries.

This is how my files look.

routes/routes.go

```
    package routes

    import (
        "cfengine-service/db"
        "encoding/json"
        "net/http"
        "strings"

        log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    )

    // Route - struct modal for routes
    type Route struct {
        Name        string
        EndPoint    string
        Methods     []string
        HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
    }
    var dbHandler = &db.Mongo{}

    // SetupRouter - returns the mux router
    func SetupRouter() *mux.Router {
        err := dbHandler.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        router := mux.NewRouter()
        for _, route := range SetUpRoutes() {
            router.HandleFunc(route.EndPoint, route.HandlerFunc).Methods(route.Methods...)
        }
        return router

    }
    func SetUpRoutes() []Route {
        return []Route{
            {
                "Host config Management",
                "/configs/group",
                []string{"GET", "POST"},
                GroupConfig,
            },
    }

func GroupConfig(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reqMethod := r.Method
    if reqMethod == "GET" {
        GetGroupConfig(w, r)
    } else if reqMethod == "POST" {
        NewGroupConfig(w, r)
    }

}

func GetGroupConfig(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    // g := r.URL.Query().Get("groupname")
    g := r.FormValue("groupname")
    if g == "" {
        if data, err := dbHandler.ReadAllGroups(); StatusWriter(w, err) {
            _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
        }
    } else {
        if data, err := dbHandler.ReadOneGroup(g); StatusWriter(w, err) {
            _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
        }
    }

}

// NewGroupConfig - end point for creating new config group
func NewGroupConfig(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    var group db.GroupConfig
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&group)
    StatusWriter(w, err)

    err = dbHandler.CreateGroupConfig(&group)
    StatusWriter(w, err)
}
```

**db/db.go**

```
    package db

    import (
        "cfengine-service/config"
        "cfengine-service/helpers"
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "time"

        log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    )

    type HostConfig struct {
        Hostname  string            `bson:"_id" json:"hostname"`
        Type      string            `bson:"type" json:"type"`
        Groups    []string          `bson:"groups" json:"groups"`
        Overrides map[string]string `bson:"overrides" json:"overrides"`
        Excludes  []string          `bson:"excludes" json:"excludes"`
        Data      map[string]string `bson:"data" json:"data"`
    }


    // Mongo collection
    type Mongo struct {
        collection *mongo.Collection
    }

    // Storage is interface for db operations
    type Storage interface {
        Connect() error
        ReadAll() ([]HostConfig, error)
        ReadOne() (*HostConfig, error)
        CreateHostConfig(h *HostConfig) error
        CreateGroupConfig(g *GroupConfig) error
        DeleteHostConfig(h *HostConfig) error
        UpdateHostGrops(h string, g string, opr string) error
        validateGroup(ctx context.Context, val string) error
    }

    func (m *Mongo) Connect() error {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
        defer cancel()
        //client, err := mongo.NewClient(config.Config.MongoURI)
        client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(config.Config.MongoURI))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        log.Info("Connected to MongoDB.....")
        m.collection = client.Database(config.Config.MongoDbName).Collection(config.Config.MongoCollectionName)
        return nil
    }
func (m *Mongo) CreateGroupConfig(g *GroupConfig) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    data, err := bson.Marshal(g)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err.Error())
        return err
    }
    _, err = m.collection.InsertOne(ctx, data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *Mongo) ReadOneGroup(g string) (GroupConfig, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()
    var group GroupConfig
    err := m.collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": g}).Decode(&group)
    if err != nil {
        return GroupConfig{}, err
    }

    return group, nil
}

func (m *Mongo) ReadAllGroups() ([]GroupConfig, error) {
    var configs []GroupConfig
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cur, err := m.collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"type": "group"})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx)
    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var record GroupConfig
        if err = cur.Decode(&record); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        configs = append(configs, record)
    }
    return configs, nil
}
```

So using the `mockgen` package i generated the mocks for `Storage` interface in my `db.go` but I am not sure how do I start using that. Here is how mock_db.go looks.

**mock_db.go**

```
type MockStorage struct {
    ctrl     *gomock.Controller
    recorder *MockStorageMockRecorder
}

// MockStorageMockRecorder is the mock recorder for MockStorage
type MockStorageMockRecorder struct {
    mock *MockStorage
}

// NewMockStorage creates a new mock instance
func NewMockStorage(ctrl *gomock.Controller) *MockStorage {
    mock := &MockStorage{ctrl: ctrl}
    mock.recorder = &MockStorageMockRecorder{mock}
    return mock
}

// EXPECT returns an object that allows the caller to indicate expected use
func (m *MockStorage) EXPECT() *MockStorageMockRecorder {
    return m.recorder
}

// Connect mocks base method
func (m *MockStorage) Connect() error {
    m.ctrl.T.Helper()
    ret := m.ctrl.Call(m, "Connect")
    ret0, _ := ret[0].(error)
    return ret0
}

// Connect indicates an expected call of Connect
func (mr *MockStorageMockRecorder) Connect() *gomock.Call {
    mr.mock.ctrl.T.Helper()
    return mr.mock.ctrl.RecordCallWithMethodType(mr.mock, "Connect", reflect.TypeOf((*MockStorage)(nil).Connect))
}
func (m *MockStorage) CreateGroupConfig(arg0 *db.GroupConfig) error {
    m.ctrl.T.Helper()
    ret := m.ctrl.Call(m, "CreateGroupConfig", arg0)
    ret0, _ := ret[0].(error)
    return ret0
}

// CreateGroupConfig indicates an expected call of CreateGroupConfig
func (mr *MockStorageMockRecorder) CreateGroupConfig(arg0 interface{}) *gomock.Call {
    mr.mock.ctrl.T.Helper()
    return mr.mock.ctrl.RecordCallWithMethodType(mr.mock, "CreateGroupConfig", reflect.TypeOf((*MockStorage)(nil).CreateGroupConfig), arg0)
}
```

So can anyone please guide me here or give me some hints to move in right direction.

Comment: Your handlers are using a package variable `var dbHandler = &db.Mongo{}` for the database. You could overwrite that with a value of your mock type in your tests, or better, refactor your code to allow injecting a database provider instead of making a global assumption that it will be `db.Mongo`.

Comment: @Adrian can you pleas share some example code please.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in testing handlers you are making is you are creating new objects so-called "Singleton object" inside the `SetupRouter` function, for all dependencies required to your application should be instantiated in `main.go` and take them as an interface where you need them. Also define small interfaces - ideal interface size is 1 or 2 methods.

`// Storage is an interface that you already have, this way you can pass your mock object while unit testing, Router should also be an interface.`

```
func SetupRouter(db Storage, router Router) *mux.Router {

        err := db.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //router := mux.NewRouter() - you do not need to do this now
        // then perform whateven actions you want to do with router
}
```

So the above snippet is just a sample that how you can mock the dependencies which in your case DB, but as @Adrian said in a comment, if this code is production code, this requires a lot of refactoring.